# EFCore - Denormalize complex property field into parent table

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Maybe this has a simple answer and the thing is that I don't know how to call this.

I have a domain model that is something like this:

```cs
public class Employee 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Company 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Pay no mind to the actual fields; what matters is that both `Employee` and `Company` have a `Address` property.

In the database, I don't want to have a normalized Address table. I could, of course, but I don't think it's worth it. What I want is to have every field of the Address object directly in the owning types tables; That would mean that both the Employee and the Company table would have a Street column, a City column, and so on.

In EF, I know how to map Address to the parents table - something like:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().ToTable("Employee");

    // ... 
}
```

And that is clearly not what I wanted - Address would be always mapped to Employee, I also need all it fields on the Company table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Owned Entity Types and even the documentation has an almost identical example as to your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a value converter. First mark the Address Type with the NotMapped attribute so that we neither have to define a primary key nor the relationship to the other tables.

```
[NotMapped]
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

The Employee and Company type stay unchanged.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

We then can add following code to the OnModelCreating method to register our value converters. In the database the generated JSON is stored as a string. Whenever we retrieve a value we need to deserialize it to an Address.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(emp => emp.Address)
            .HasConversion(address => JsonSerializer.Serialize(address, null),
               addressFromDb => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Address>(addressFromDb, null));
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .Property(comp => comp.Address)
            .HasConversion(address => JsonSerializer.Serialize(address, null),
               addressFromDb => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Address>(addressFromDb, null));
```

Comment: That's a very good tip - didn't know I could set conversions like this.

Comment: @BrunoBrant. Problem here that you can not use properties of such objects in filter.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Oh, it's certainly limited. Your answer is the one I was looking for. But I haven't mastered all that EF provides and it's nice to learn new things like this.